# Why can't I get Eclipse / EPIC to display line numbers?

Tags: eclipse, epic

I installed EPIC, but I cannot see the line number even I enable line number, any idea?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

Goto:

1. Window->Preferences->Perl Epic->Editor, then place a check beside "Show line numbers."
2. Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Test Editors, then UNCHECK Show line numbers.
3. Click Apply.
4. If the line numbers do not show up, right click on the left margin of the perl file you are viewing and click "Show Line Numbers" from the popup menu.

Make sure you uncheck the one in the general settings and check the one for the EPIC settings.

You may need to restart Eclipse to see the line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Perl Epic->Editor, then check "Show line numbers."